# Error "libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file" after installing Node.js via Homebrew on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: node.js, installation, node-modules, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I encountered an error while attempting to install Node.js version 16 on my Windows system using Homebrew in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). After successfully installing Node.js with the command:

```
brew install node@16
```

I tried to check the Node.js version using node --version, but it returned the following error:

```
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or    directory
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm experiencing an error after installing Node.js 16 via Homebrew in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). When checking the version with node --version, I get: "node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Despite reinstalling Node.js and updating Homebrew, the issue persists. Seeking guidance to resolve and use Node.js 16 in WSL. Any insights appreciated. Thank you.